# Missing shadow: why?

Tags: unity, lighting

In these scene, i can't figure why, my player, and object it place, can't cast shadow on floor.

All other static objects in scene cast shodow correctly.

There is a floor with it's material, then there is also a Reflection probe.

Is Reflection Probe something that influence shadow cast correctly ?

Follow, floor proprieties

[image]

Floor material proprieties:

[image]

My Lights: 
[image]

My scene:

[image: My scene]

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of the shadow-casting object's renderer and material too?

Comment: Do you have shadows enabled on each Light component? Are you using the correct "Quality" configuration in "Project Settings" (Very low, low, medium, high, Ultra ...)?